# Kendo Grid sometimes renders data sometimes does not

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

I have a dynamic Kendo grid, for which I get the data every time from the server with the column configuration. The grids renders the data as expected, but sometimes the grid does not render the data at all and only renders the column headers. The grid does not even recognize the column configuration, which mentions whether the column is hidden or not, column title etc.

When I refresh(ctrl+f5) the browser page the grids starts displaying normally.
When I checked the html generated in both cases I saw following difference

1- The Grid which displays correctly

Has a `thead` and `tbody` inside a single table

2- The Grid which does not display the data

Has two different divs for header and content

Please see the following image for Good Grid

[image]

And following image for Bad Grid

[image]

I am not sure why the same grid has two different htmls? Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**

One more thing that might be helpful.

The kendo grid definition is in a content.html file. And this file is used as a content URL for kendo tabstrip control. There are around 7 tabs and all the tabs are refering to the same content file.

Comment: Are you sure the data are returning correctly? It might be because one of the columns is not handling the exception.

Comment: The data is fetched from the server. I see no exceptions on the console neither on the server.

Comment: Does the lack of data happen with the same set of `custom` data i.e. if you ran the same configuration 10 times would 1 of those not pull back data or is it when you are changing the set up i.e. introducing different columns? How are you initializing the setup of the grid? Can you provide a simple example to demonstrate the behaviour?

Comment: The grid is dynamic and everytime it changes and has different set of columns. here is [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ohICE/13) I created sometime back to give you an idea how it should work. The only difference is that the code snippet in the dojo uses static data and in my scenario i get the data from the server

Comment: Wait are you trying to update the columns dynamically?  In other words are you dynamically changing the schema?

Comment: Yes that is correct!